# signature mismatch on zip downloaded from github

Tags: git, security, github, download, versioning

When I click the "download zip" button for a package on github, or download a particular commit by https://github.com/{username}/{projectname}/archive/{sha}.zip, the sha1sum of the file ends up on my computer does not agree with the one shown on webpage.

Why is this occurring? It is unsafe for the sha1sum to not match. How do I download a commit's full source code with verifiable hashsum without using "git" command or having to make an account on github (because I want to just once download the library for local use, not edit it).

Thank you!

Comment: The SHA-1 shown is the id of the git commit. You should clone the git repository, and check the SHA-1 of the last commit matches with what you're seeing it on the web.

Answer (score 4):

Downloading a repo source content with the following url...

`https://github.com/{username}/{projectname}/archive/{sha}.zip`

...will retrieve the code source contained in the commit with the following url

`https://github.com/{username}/{projectname}/commits/{sha}`

Running `sha1sum` on the retrieved archive will **not** produce the sha of the targeted commit.

The way Git relies on SHA-1 hashes to uniquely identify its internal objects is explained in detail in **[this chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)** of the **[Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/)** book. You'll notice that the sha of any commit will depend on the sha of its parent commit (and indirectly of all its ancestors). This means that in order to produce such a sha, you would need the whole history of all the changes that lead to this commit.

In order to securely verify that the source code hasn't been altered and matches the commit sha displayed on GitHub, there's no other way than cloning the full repository and running the following command. This command will update your working directory with the content of the commit.

`git checkout {sha}`

If git cannot find a commit that matches this sha, the command will fail.

Comment: So nowhere does the github site display a checksum of individual commits, especially the latest commit, for validation?

Comment: Indeed, you won't **currently** find a way to validate with sha1sum something downloaded from GitHub. However, you may want to try and ask GitHub for such a feature by sending them a mail to **support@github.com**.

Comment: @user2733762 If this answer was helpful to you, maybe could you consider accepting it?